# Writing records to a database and only the first character of each field is entered

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I've written 2 records to a database. The first record was written in SSMS and shows up fine. The second record was written using a call for a stored procedure in VS and this record only shows the first letters of each field. The only fields in the second record that show properly are the date fields. All the columns are present.

The call for the Stored Procedure happens on a button click and runs through an interface to the class that has the create method.

I've put a breakpoint on the create method and all the values passed in from textboxes are what they are supposed to be.

Obviously something isn't quite right here and I just can't seem to find where I've gone wrong.
Sorry if this is a bit lengthy but any help would be greatly appreciated!

SQL INSERT for the first record

```
INSERT INTO Employees(Employee_ID, Full_Name, Date_Of_Birth, Home_Email, Work_Email, Work_Phone_Ext, Work_Phone, Home_Phone, Date_Started, Manager_ID, Client_Dept, Client_Start_Date, Client_Manager_Name, Leaver, Leave_Date, Contact_Person_Name, Contact_Person_Phone) 
VALUES(0, 'Test Person1', '1982-07-05', 'test1@hometest.com', 'test1@worktest.com', '01234', '654789', '01234567891', '2006-06-15', 0, 'Test Dept', '2006-06-30', 'Dave Davidson', 'No', NULL, 'Test Cp', '085219874561')
```

SQL Stored Procedure for the second record

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Create_Employee_Personal_Details @full_name VARCHAR,
@dob DATE, @home_email VARCHAR, @work_email VARCHAR, @work_ext VARCHAR, @work_phone VARCHAR,
@home_phone VARCHAR, @start_date DATE, @manager_ID INT, @client_dept VARCHAR, 
@client_start_date DATE, @client_manager VARCHAR, @leaver VARCHAR, @leave_date DATE,
@contact_person VARCHAR, @contact_person_phone VARCHAR OUTPUT AS

DECLARE @employee_id INT

INSERT INTO Employees(Full_Name, Date_Of_Birth, Home_Email, Work_Email, Work_Phone_Ext, Work_Phone, Home_Phone, Date_Started, Manager_ID, Client_Dept, Client_Start_Date, Client_Manager_Name, Leaver, Leave_Date, Contact_Person_Name, Contact_Person_Phone)
VALUES (@full_name, @dob, @home_email, @work_email, @work_ext, @work_phone, @home_phone,
        @start_date, @manager_ID, @client_dept, @client_start_date, @client_manager,
         @leaver, @leave_date, @contact_person, @contact_person_phone)

SELECT @employee_id = MAX(Employees.Employee_ID)
FROM Employees

RETURN @employee_id
```

Call for the Stored Procedure

```
employeeID = employeeDataAccessor.Create(tbFullName, tbDob, tbHomeEmail, tbWorkEmail, tbWorkPhoneExt, tbWorkPhone,
            tbHomePhone, tbStartDate, managerID, tbClientDept, tbDateStartedClient, tbClientManager, methods.Leaver(rbYes, rbNo),
                tbDateOfLeave, tbContactPerson, tbContactPersonPhone);
```

Create method

```
public int Create(TextBox fullName, TextBox dob, TextBox homeEmail, TextBox workEmail,
        TextBox workPhoneExt, TextBox workPhone, TextBox homePhone, TextBox startDate, int managerID, TextBox clientDept,
            TextBox dateStartedClient, TextBox clientManager, string yesNo,TextBox dateOfLeave, TextBox contactPerson, TextBox cpPhoneNo)
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    connection.Open();

    var cmdIntoEmployees = new SqlCommand("EmployeeSystemProject.dbo.Create_Employee_Personal_Details", connection);
    cmdIntoEmployees.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", fullName.Text);
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", Convert.ToDateTime(dob.Text));
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@home_email", homeEmail.Text);
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@work_email", workEmail.Text);
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@work_ext", workPhoneExt.Text);
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@work_phone", workPhone.Text);
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@home_phone", homePhone.Text);
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start_date", Convert.ToDateTime(startDate.Text));
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manager_ID", managerID);
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_dept", clientDept.Text);
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_start_date", Convert.ToDateTime(dateStartedClient.Text));
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_manager", clientManager.Text);
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@leaver", yesNo);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateOfLeave.Text) == false)
    {
        cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@leave_date", Convert.ToDateTime(dateOfLeave.Text));
    }
    else
    {
        cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@leave_date", DBNull.Value);
    }

    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_person", contactPerson.Text);
    cmdIntoEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_person_phone", cpPhoneNo.Text);

    employeeID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdIntoEmployees.ExecuteScalar());

    return employeeID;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified length for your parameters in your Stored Procedure:

```
@home_phone VARCHAR,
```

This will consider `@home_phone` parameter to have a default length  of `1`. So when you pass it a value like `1-123-456-7890` it will only consider first character as the part of input, and the rest of the values will be truncated. That is why, you only see a single character in your fields. Specify your length according to field size in table. For example, if your field `home_phone` has a size of `14` then specify the same length with your parameter in Stored Procedure.

```
@home_phone VARCHAR(14)
```

See: [char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms176089.aspx)

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, **the default length is 1.** When n is not specified when
>   using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.